# How to add clickable logo on the flash web player?

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

I have a code like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.clipul.com/play/swfobject.js"></script>
<div id="player">This text will be replaced</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var so = new SWFObject('http://montsmile.com/jwplayer/player.swf','mpl','480','380','8');
so.addParam('allowscriptaccess','always');
so.addParam('allowfullscreen','true');
so.addVariable('height','310');
so.addVariable('width','470');
so.addVariable('file','http://localhost:81/newtip/<?=$videopath1?>');
so.addVariable('logo','http://localhost:81/newtip/ffmpeg/logo2.jpg');
so.addVariable("ClickURL", "http://www.google.com");
so.addVariable('captions','/upload/corrie.xml');
so.addVariable('link','<?=$full_url.'tip.php?vid='.$row_video['vid']?>');
so.addVariable('linkfromdisplay','true');
so.addVariable('linktarget','_blank');
so.addVariable('searchbar','false');
so.addVariable('skin','http://montsmile.com/jwplayer/player.swf');
so.write('player');
</script>
```

It is displaying a player and playing the video. If I Click on the Logo It has to go to www.google.com. But when I click on the logo it becomes pause.

Help me how to add clickable Logo on the player

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add the following line to your embed code:

```
so.addVariable('logo.link','http://www.google.com/');
```

Best,

Zach

Developer, LongTail Video

Comment: Hi Zach,
Thanks for your reply.

But It is also not working. When i click on the logo it becomes pause.